# Countif and look up in two sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use a variation of a `countif` formula across two sheets. I want to count the number of times an agent of mine is a "Yes" in column A based on how many times their name appears in column A. BUt I want to pull this information from one google sheet to a completely different sheet in another doc.

`COUNTIF` paired with `IMPORTRANGE`

It should be giving me a count of `3`, but I am getting `0`.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to run your `IMPORTRANGE` formula alone and **Allow access**. then when sheets are connected you just do:

```
=COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("ID-or-URL", "Sheet1!A1:A"), "yes")
```

[image: 0]